# Troubles understanding complex law related sentence

Tags: translation

I'm an intermediate German speaker and I'm having problems making sense of the following sentence:

> Nach Ablauf der genannten Frist ist der Anspruch verwirkt, sofern er dem Arbeitgeber gegenüber            nicht vorher erfolglos geltend gemacht wurde.

Even though I understand all the words by now, the meaning somehow doesn't make sense. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What parts are you having trouble with. I suppose with the "nicht"? For a law text this is actually rather low complexity. Try replacing "sofern" by "if".

Comment: Ist es nicht eine tolle Sprache ...?! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Ohne Kontext wissen wir nichts von genannten und ungenannten Fristen. Zur Analyse können wir das genannt unter den Tisch fallen lassen in der Hoffnung, es gäbe ohnehin nur eine Frist von der die Rede war:

> Nach Ablauf der Frist ist der Anspruch verwirkt, sofern er dem Arbeitgeber gegenüber nicht vorher erfolglos geltend gemacht wurde.

Wäre ein Anspruch erfolgreich geltend gemacht worden, dann gäbe es wohl keinen Streit. Es gab also einen Anspruch, dieser ist dem Arbeitgeber (AG) gegenüber geltend gemacht worden - leider erfolglos.

> Nach Ablauf der Frist ist der Anspruch verwirkt, sofern er dem Arbeitgeber gegenüber nicht vorher geltend gemacht wurde.

Jemand hat also einen Anspruch dem AG gegenüber fristgerecht geltend gemacht, sprich, geäußert oder der Anspruch ist verwirkt.

Der Anspruch kann also verwirkt sein weil man ihn gar nicht, oder nicht fristgerecht geäußert hat.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a complete example.

> Gegenseitige Ansprüche aus dem Beschäftigungsverhältnis (z.B. aus
>   Mehrarbeit, rückständigem Gehalt/Lohn u.ä.) sind innerhalb von 2
>   Monaten geltend zu machen. Bei Beendigung des
>   Beschäftigungsverhältnisses sind alle daraus herrührenden sonstigen
>   Ansprüche innerhalb von 3 Monaten nach Beendigung geltend zu machen.
>   Nach Ablauf der genannten Fristen ist der Anspruch verwirkt, sofern er
>   dem Arbeitgeber gegenüber nicht vorher erfolglos geltend gemacht
>   wurde.

This means you have to post any claims within 3 months of the termination of the contract. The last sentence (your question) just clarifies. If you don't (nicht vorher geltend gemacht) your possible claim is forfeited. The "erfolglos" is just filling since it must be a non successful claim otherwise you wouldn't be having a claim after the 3 month period.

Answer (score 1):

Es geht um Forderungen dem Arbeitgeber gegenüber, also sehr wahrscheinlich um Lohn. In der Frage fehlt tatsächlich etwas der Kontext, ich versuche den mal zu konstruieren. Angenommen, der Arbeitgeber hat den Lohn nicht oder nicht vollständig bezahlt, dann muss man sich innerhalb einer bestimmten Frist beschweren. Wenn man sich rechtzeitig beschwert, dann verjährt der Anspruch gemäss diesem Artikel nicht. Wenn aber die Frist abläuft und man sich nicht meldet (oder etwa gar nicht merkt, dass einmal ein Monatslohn nicht bezahlt wurde), ist der Anspruch verwirkt.

Answer (score 1):

the sentence has 2 parts:

1) after the end of the deadline the demand/claim... is declared void/invalidated,

2) unless the claim wasnt already unsuccessfully (double negative) submitted to the employer before.

I dont know, whether the second part has any meaning in your context. With the double negation, I have a feeling, they just might not want to have the trouble twice. German employment law is the most complicated of all law books in Germany. Employers, companies, landlords write often phrases in contracts, which they want the other contracter to do, but are meaningless in a court. Maybe ask a real German lawyer.

Comment: The second part means that, for the claim to remain valid, you have to have made an unsuccessful "claim" to your employer. Example: your employer owes you 1000 dollars. You can prove it. 2 years later you still don't have the money. You go to a lawyer. He asks you whether you have made an attempt to get the money... like writing an official claim to your employer. If you say "Yes, I did, but he wouldn't pay" then the lawyer will help you

Comment: There is no double negative in the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> Nach Ablauf der genannten Frist ist der Anspruch verwirkt, sofern er dem Arbeitgeber gegenüber nicht vorher erfolglos geltend gemacht wurde.

It's actually a fairly simple German legalese sentence. It is easy to understand if you see that it has two parts:

> Nach Ablauf der genannten Frist ist der Anspruch verwirkt

Translation: After the end of the forementioned deadline, the claim is forfeit.

Meaning: If you don't make the deadline, you don't have a claim anymore. If you went to court after the deadline, the court would throw the case out without looking at the merits.

> sofern er

unless... - this part is the exception to the rule. German legal texts always follow this structure: First the general rule, then the exceptions or special cases.

> dem Arbeitgeber gegenüber nicht vorher erfolglos geltend gemacht wurde.

Translation: was before (the deadline) asserted without success against the employer.

Meaning: If you asserted your claim to the employer before the deadline, the claim is not forfeit even when the deadline passes.

So putting it all together:

Your claims against the employer are forfeit if you do not enforce them before the deadline. Except if you asserted them to the employer before the deadline.

Example: He didn't pay your salary.

- If you go to court before the deadline, you have a case.
- If you go to court after the deadline, *but notified the employer before the deadline that he still owes you the salary*, you also have a case.
- If do nothing until the deadline (neither notify the employer nor go to court), you have nothing. If you try to go to court after this, your case will be thrown out.